# Date format in jquery datepicker on WP

Tags: jquery, wordpress

What I am trying to achieve is to add a datepicker to a custom post in wordpress and have it save the date in the format of yyyy-mm-dd. Currently it is saving in a dd-mm-yyy format. What really has me puzzled is the fact that changes to my js file does not seem to have any effect. I've been reading SO posts for hours now, so a hint in the right direction would be very welcome. I'm currently working in a child theme of twentytwenty.

functions.php:

```
function ca_load_jquery_datepicker() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-style', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');
    wp_register_script('date-picker', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/date-picker.js', array('jquery'), '1.1', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('date-picker');
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'ca_load_jquery_datepicker' );
```

date-picker.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.date').datepicker({
    dateFormat : 'yyyy-mm-dd'
  });
});
```

I can comment out all of the js file and yet will still be working.

I can call the date picker with:

```
<input type="text" class="date" name="dato" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $dato ); ?>" />
```

I realize that this could also be easily done with a plugin, but I'd like to understand also what is going on.

Comment: As you make the js file changes, ensure to clear browser cache between changes. Running the browser in incognito/private mode can avoid this hassle while developing/testing.

Comment: Of course. I hadn't even thought that it would cache the js. It is working beautifully now. I feel rather silly now, to be honest.

Comment: No worries, many have crossed the "cache fight", including me! ... the same can happen with CSS changes too. Feel free to delete this question if you prefer.